# Turn a number $x$ into a fraction with a denominator with no more than $k$ digits

Tags: fractions

Is there a function for turning any number $x$ into a fraction with a denominator that has a maximum of $k$ digits?  (I'm sure there is, since Excel has one built in, I just can't figure out what it is.)

For example, $f(0.1234) = $

- $\frac{106}{859}$ where $k=3$;
- $\frac{10}{81}$ where $k=2$;
- $\frac{1}{8}$ where $k=1$.

Comment: A reasonably good answer can be found from the [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansion of $x$.

Comment: I would call the continued fraction answer the best answer, in certain quantifiable ways. @AndréNicolas

Comment: One could complicate things by looking at secondary convergents, but there is probably no point.

Comment: For example, the continued fraction expansion for $0.1234$ yields convergents $0,1/8,9/73, 10/81, 19/154, 29/235, 106/859, 135/1094, 241/1953, 376/3047, 617/5000=0.1234$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, would you like to make that comment into an answer?